# Program using noexcept accepted by msvc and clang but rejected by gcc

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, noexcept, narrowing, exception-specification

I am learning C++ using the books listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, I recently learnt about `noexcept` using the book *C++ Primer*. Now, to further clear my concept of the topic and to confirm that I've understood things correctly, I am writing simple programs. One such program that compiles with MSVC and Clang but not with GCC is given below. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hso9rG7as).

```
void f() noexcept(5) //accepted by msvc but rejected by gcc
{

}
```

So **my question is** which compiler is right here(if any)?

Here are the results for some of the major compilers:

| Compiler | C++ Version | Accepts-Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GCC | C++17 | No |
| GCC | C++20 | No |
| Clang | C++17 | Yes |
| Clang | C++20 | No |
| MSVC | C++17 | Yes |
| MSVC | C++20 | Yes |

As we can see the program works with some compilers but not with others. The error in gcc says:  `error: narrowing conversion of '5' from 'int' to 'bool'`

Comment: What is 5 supposed to mean?

Comment: Looks like ill-formed and compilers accepting code are wrong.

Comment: One might assume that 5 is being interpreted as true.

Comment: This was changed after C++17 from well-formed to ill-formed with [CWG 2039](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2039.html). Cppreference lists it as DR against C++11. Clang implements it as such as well if you use the later version in both your test cases. MSVC seems to have not implemented this.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87724 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95564 related

Answer (score 9):

##### TLDR

The program is **ill-formed** and the respective **compilers are wrong in accepting the code** because the int prvalue expression `5` is not a *contextually converted constant expression of type `bool`* which(if supplied) is required to be a contextually converted constant expression by the `noexcept-specifier`. Basically, the reason for the program being ill-formed is the same for why `bool b{5};` is ill-formed as well i.e., this involves a **narrowing conversion**.

---

From [exception specification documentation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/except.spec):

> **1)** The exception specification is either defined implicitly,
> or defined explicitly by using a noexcept-specifier as a suffix of a function declarator
>
> ```
> noexcept-specifier:
>   noexcept ( constant-expression )
>   noexcept
>   throw ( )
> ```
>
> **2)** In a noexcept-specifier, **the constant-expression, if supplied, shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool**; that constant expression is the exception specification of the function type in which the noexcept-specifier appears.

(emphasis mine)

This means that for the program to be well-formed the supplied constant expression(which is `5` in our example) needs to be a  *contextually converted constant expression of type bool*.

Now lets see from [expr.const#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#4) whether `5` is a contextually converted constant expression or not:

> **4.10)** A contextually converted constant expression of type bool is an expression, contextually converted to bool, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the conversion sequence **contains only the conversions above**.
>
> **4.7)** integral conversions **other than narrowing conversions**,

And from [narrowing conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#7)

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type**.

(emphasis mine)

This means that the conversion from int prvalue `5` to bool `true` is a narrowing conversion and so `5` is not a contextually converted constant expression of type bool and so the program is ill-formed and the respective compilers are wrong in accepting the code.

Basically, the reason for the program being ill-formed is that same as to why `bool b{3};` is ill-formed. You can even see the you'll get the same error. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/53eefbqfj)

---

Here is the msvc bug report:

[MSVC accepts invalid narrowing conversion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-narrowing-conversio/10165173?)

Here is the clang bug report:

[Clang accepts invalid narrowing conversion](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58200)

Comment: Is it just UB, or is diagnostic required?

Comment: @DanielLangr: Ill-formed is not UB; it's ill-formed.

Comment: @DanielLangr Not UB just ill-formed.